# Вопрос про ссылочный тип возвращаемого значения

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки

1. Не очень понимаю, что значит возвращаем ссылку на элемент, ведь `b` типа `int`, а чтобы была ссылка на него=возвр типу, это что ли создается переменная типа `int& = b`, и она возвращается? Понятно, что мы вернули значение `b` в `return`, а потом на `}` значение стерлось из памяти, но почему при этом в `x` мусор, если уже успели его инициализировать?

```
int& foo() {
    int b = 0;
    return b;
}

int main() {
    int x = foo();
}
```

В общем, произошла какая-то сильная путаница с ссылками

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как происходит вся эта работа с ссылками

Comment: Путаница. Только в представлениях о том, что такое ссылка. Так нельзя, но не потому, что что-то не работает в инициализации `int x = foo();`, а потому, что возврат в `foo()` ссылки на локальную переменную, которой при выходе уже больше нет..

Comment: ну я понимаю, что ссылка это просто как другое название переменной, которое ничего не занимает в памяти. Но вот тут в функции мы же нигде не объявляли ссылку, но при этом ее как-то возвращаем

Comment: Ссылка - это не другое название переменной, она очень даже может занимать место в памяти и объявлена она тут как возвращаемое значение функции. В `x` мусор так как значение, на которое ссылалась возвращенная ссылка, протухло сразу после возврата функции (до инициализации `x`).

Comment: `почему при этом в x мусор, если уже успели его инициализировать?` Не успели. Последовательность действий _примерно_ выглядит так. Есть некоторая временная скрытая переменная `temp`, которая инициализируется переменной `b` при выполнении `return`: `int& temp = b;`. Затем функция `foo` заканчивает свою работу, переменная `b` уничтожается, и ссылка `temp` перестаёт указывать на живой объект. Затем невалидная ссылка `temp` используется для инициализации переменной `x`: `int x = temp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как это выглядит в VC++ 2022 при компиляции с отключенной оптимизацией (с включенной `foo()` вообще выбрасывается:

```
; 17   : int& foo() {
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx
; 18   :     int b = 0;
    mov DWORD PTR _b$[ebp], 0
; 19   :     return b;
    lea eax, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
```

Т.е. в регистр `eax` записывается *адрес* переменной `b`.

Затем в `main()`

```
; 23   :     int x = foo();
    call    ?foo@@YAAEAHXZ              ; foo
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov DWORD PTR x$[rsp], eax
```

*после выхода из `foo()`* (читай — после уничтожения переменной `b`) значение по этому адресу записывается в переменную `x`.